# Anyone know how to use "S.M.A.R.T Data and Self Checks " to determine whether or not a HDD is failing?

Tags: hard-drive, gnome-disk-utility

Okay, so I'm not entirely sure if this is the right place to ask this question but I genuinely don't know the meaning behind what pops up when I use this function of the "Disks" program. I'm currently trying to examine the HDD of my brother's PS4 because it's been having issues booting up and properly functioning after having been shut off.

I guess what I'm trying to ask about is what the categories "Normalized", "Threshold", "Worst", and "Types" mean.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/smart for many posts on the subject. You can insert search terms in the search bar up top where you see "Search on Ask Ubuntu" to find results for key phrases from your error messages, then click on the Votes button right of center to sort up the answers found helpful by the most folks. That's why it's important to click on the up arrow and the checkmark on answers which solve problems.

Comment: Yeah, this has me going in the right direction and (for the most part) answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually SMART gives you an indication of what it is happening, the metrics information presented differ from HDD manufacturer.

On a gran scheme if you start to see something like "uncorrectable sector or errors, or re-allocated sectors, or something referencing Spin" is a good indication to take action and replace the HDD.

Usually I would go to the manufactured of the HDD and look there for any value to correlate.

Here is a link to wiki for some reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

Hope this sign post you in the right direction.

MEMA

Comment: I'll also be keeping this in mind as well. Thanks for the tip.